# What is the type of bathroom faucet that mounts from the top?

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

I have a sink where the original owner remodeled into a tight space. Now I need to replace the widespread faucet and am having troubles finding the correct mounting type. Because of the tight space, the cabinet is under-sized for the sink so the sink bowl interferes slightly with the holes so a traditional faucet that tightens from underneath the deck is generally impossible. The sink that I removed had a large nut at the bottom of the deck but mounted from the top of the sink. I cannot find someone who knows the name of this type of faucet mount.

What type of faucet would I be looking for that mounts from the top like this?

I've added a picture from underneath the sink to describe what it looks like.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking if there are lav faucets that don't require fastening from below? I have never seen one except for those that mount on the wall... normally you select compatible cabinet, sink, and faucet prior to installing anything...

Comment: [How do I install a faucet with TopMount bracket?](http://globeunion.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1753) – globeunion.custhelp.com - *top mount* or *quick dock*. - Or any faucet that comes with screws in the locking nuts...

Comment: ... like this $300 one from [wayfair.com](https://www.wayfair.com/Gerber--Sirius-Trim-Line-Widespread-Bathroom-Faucet-D304644-L655-K~CBGG1240.html?refid=GX434629554673-CBGG1240_50632844&device=c&ptid=933996800057&network=g&targetid=pla-933996800057&channel=GooglePLA&ireid=121368142&fdid=1817&PiID%5B%5D=50632844&gclid=Cj0KCQiApsiBBhCKARIsAN8o_4jal143h1iaO9C9Tkx0sfwnGpu7wZQu7KAPOknms2r5MCXUUq3eD98aAh2FEALw_wcB)